# How to draw a gradient color background for a UITableView section of grouped Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, background, gradient

I need to custom a **section** including several cells of an UITableView in a **grouped** style. Actually, I'd like to set a gradient color background to each section of cells. The number of cells per section can change.

I'v found out a lot of solutions to custom one background per cell but not to custom a section of cells.

for exemple, the following code set a background color per cell of each section :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    

[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

CAGradientLayer *grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
grad.frame = cell.bounds;
grad.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];
grad.cornerRadius = 5.0;

[cell setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
[cell.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:grad atIndex:0];


CAGradientLayer *selectedGrad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
selectedGrad.frame = cell.bounds;
selectedGrad.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];

[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
[cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:selectedGrad atIndex:0];

}
```

This is not what I need to achieve, I have to set a linear gradient color for all the cells for each section.

If anyone had faced the same issue and found out a solution, please let us know

Thanks a lot